# Expression.Condition(nullableType.HasValue, new classInstance(){ ... }, null) can it be done some other way?

Tags: linq, lambda, expression-trees

I am working on a projection utility and have one last (more?) hurdle to clear...

Here is the scenario:

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int? AddressID { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }
    public string Otherproperty1 { get; set; }
    public string Otherproperty2 { get; set; }
    public string Otherproperty3 { get; set; }
    public string Otherproperty4 { get; set; }
}

public class PersonSummary
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int? AddressID { get; set; }
    public AddressSummary Address { get; set; }

}

public class Address
{
    public int AddressID { get; set; }
    public string HouseNumber { get; set; }
    public string StreetName { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public int Zip { get; set; }
    public string Otherproperty1 { get; set; }
    public string Otherproperty2 { get; set; }
    public string Otherproperty3 { get; set; }
    public string Otherproperty4 { get; set; }
}

public class AddressSummary
{
    public int AddressID { get; set; }
    public string HouseNumber { get; set; }
    public string StreetName { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public int Zip { get; set; }
}
```

I successfully have my utility working something like this:

```
ProjectionUtility.Project<Person,PersonSummary>();
```

Which will return this Expression Lambda:

```
p => new PersonSummary(){
    FirstName = p.FirstName,
    LastName = p.LastName,
    AddressID = p.AddressID,
    Address = p.AddressID.HasValue
        ? new AddressSummary(){ AddressID = p.Address.AddressID, HouseNumber = p.Address.HouseNumber, etc... }
        : new AddressSummary(){}
}
```

My goal is to be able to set Address = null if the AddressID.HasValue is false like so:

```
p => new PersonSummary(){
    FirstName = p.FirstName,
    LastName = p.LastName,
    AddressID = p.AddressID,
    Address = p.AddressID.HasValue
        ? new AddressSummary(){ AddressID = p.Address.AddressID, HouseNumber = p.Address.HouseNumber, etc... }
        : null
}
```

This is easily done "manually", however when I try to programatically create this lambda using expressions, I'm stuck...

I am currently using what essentially breaks down to this (I know the syntax isn't right, but I did it this way to in an attempt to show what it is I'm doing):

```
Expression.Condition(
    p.AddressID.HasValue,
    new AddressSummary(){},
    new AddressSummary(){});
```

If I try this:

```
Expression.Condition(
    p.AddressID.HasValue,
    new AddressSummary(){},
    null);
```

I can't because iftrue and iffalse must be the same type (AddressSummary) so I am stuck at the moment creating a new AddressSummary for the iffalse argument.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't see how the case that allegedly works could possibly work!  `Expression.Condition` takes parameters of type **Expression**, of which `AddressSummary` does not qualify.  (And neither does `bool`, the first argument.)

Comment: Kirk, I'll quote my own post here..."I know the syntax isn't right, but I did it this way to in an attempt to show what it is I'm doing".  Hope that makes sense...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cast your null to the correct type. In this case:

```
Expression.Condition(
    p.AddressID.HasValue,
    new AddressSummary(){},
    (AddressSummary)null);
```

null can be any (reference) type, but by default it is of type System.Object. If you want it to be another type, you have to tell it.

Comment: The OP's example is deeply flawed such that your answer is not accurate -- `Expression.Condition` only takes parameters of type `Expression`; there is no ambiguity so casting the `null` has no meaning.

Comment: Oh, yeah, good point. I guess I ignored syntax things because he said he knew the syntax wasn't right, and just tried to go with something based on the error message.

Comment: Thanks, your answer pointed me in the right direction...just needed to figure out how to create that using an expression and it worked like a charm.  i.e. - var nullRef = Expression.TypeAs(Expression.Constant(null), typeof(AddressSummary)); which essentially translates to "null As AddressSummary".